# Eventmachine memory management

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, events, eventmachine

I'm running an eventmachine process on heroku, and it seems to be hitting their memory limit of 512MB after an hour or so. I start seeing messages like this:

```
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
Process running mem=531M(103.8%)
```

I'm running a lot of events through the reactor, so I'm thinking maybe the reactor is getting backed up (I'm imagining it as a big queue)?  But there could be some other reason, I'm still fairly new to eventmachine.

Are there any good ways to profile eventmachine and and get some stats on it.  As a simple example, I was hoping to see how many events were scheduled in the queue to see if it was getting backed up and keeping those all in memory.  But if anyone has other suggestions I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leak turned out to be in Mongoid's `identity_map` (nothing to do with EventMachine). Setting `Mongoid.identity_map_enabled = false` at the beginning of the event machine process resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

I use eventmachine extensively and never ran into any memory leak inside the reactor so your bet is that the ruby code is but without knowing more about your application it is hard to give you a real answer.

The only queue I can think of right now is the thread pool, each time you use the defer method the block is either given to a free thread or queued waiting for a free thread, I suppose if all your threads are blocking waiting for something the queue could grow and use all the memory available.